# handling LTR and RTL for Arabic Sites (internationalization)

Tags: css, wordpress, right-to-left, qtranslate

I am creating a site in Wordpress,It is basically an english site but when user clicks on translate it translate it into Arabic.There is problem of `ltr` and `rtl`,How can I solve that.I am using qtranslate plugin right now.Same is the case with urdu ,kurdish languages.
Anyone who can help me with this
please see attached image[image]
Thanks

Comment: @SergeyS My site doesn't appear fine when I click on arabic,there are issues with rtl and ltr ,how can i handle that.?I can handle the words and add words in the .po file

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific. What sort of directionality problems? column order? Character order? Latin/punctuation dancing with Arabic?

Comment: @bmargulies arabic is not rtl

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a screenshot or something.

Comment: @Auxiliary please have a look

Comment: @user1765876 Arabic is not RTL? I think you don't know Arabic language.

Comment: do you add `dir='rtl'` to the `html` tag for `rtl` languages? or at least to the parent of all translated text

Comment: @user1765876 is this website live? the plugin should be inserting some info about the language in the html. so we can use that to style the elements in css

Comment: @ArashMilani I thought the same thing at first, but I think he means that the Arabic is not shown as RTL in his website.

Comment: @Auxiliary yes I mean the same,yes the website is live,I amusing qtranslate plugin,I dont know where to write the dir=rtl,can you help me?

Comment: @barts where to add this line?I am using plugin

Comment: @user1765876 when you click something to do the translation, add some code to add `dir='rtl'` to the html tag `<html dir='rtl'>`. See answers below

Comment: you can have your style_rtl.css switched with `qtrans_getLanguage()` check.

Comment: You can see my answered posts or Questions (I posted and provided answers) for your solution on this qTranslate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this wordpress plugin is inserting a language direction and name into the `<html>` tag. like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

OR

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ar-AR">
```

If I understand you the plugin is not rendering correct `direction` attribute for the `ltr` languages.

### First Option

One option is to use javascript to fix this. simply we detect the `rtl` languages by their ISO codes (here it's `ar` for Arabic) and adding a class to the `body` tag

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("html[lang=ar]").attr("dir", "rtl")
            .find("body").addClass("right-to-left");

});
```

Now you can style that elements in the theme css file by prefixing that `right-to-left` class like this: (this is just a sample)

```
body.right-to-left my-element li {
    float:right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

.

### Second Option

As suggested by the other answer Use php to insert that class name into the `body` tag of the page. open your `header.php` file in your theme and edit this line:

```
<body class=" <?php if($_GET["lang"] == "ar") echo "right-to-left"; ?> ">
```

Now use the same css to style you elements

Comment: my header.php starts with a div

Comment: It might be in different locations according to your theme. find which file has the `<body>` start tag. and apply that change to that file.

Comment: people says it is in header.php

Answer (score 1):

One simple but inefficient way is to check the language with PHP in your theme's header file and if it's Arabic or another RTL language you can add the dir="rtl" to your HTML or any tag you want. I realized that qTranslate has a GET method mode and adds something like `?lang=ar` to the URLs. So you could easily check it with PHP: `if ($_GET["lang"]=='ar') ...`

**EDIT**

You can add something like this in your theme's header file. (You can find this file from path_to_wordpress/wp-content/themes/your_theme/header.php), It's either called **header.php** or something similar.

find the `<body>` tag and add this line to the end (before the **>** sign):

```
<?php if($_GET["lang"] == "ar") echo "dir='rtl'"; ?>
```

Comment: qtranslate doesn't forward anything with URL in "lang",i mean there is no name value pair

Comment: qTranslate has 3 modes, one of them is the URL mode. See http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/

Comment: my header.php starts with a div